# Destructure array and use object shorthand assignment

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following code:

```
let id = '';
let text = '';

// Note: `match` = [full match, id (first group), text (second group)]
if (match.length > 1) {
  [, id] = match;
}
if (match.length > 2) {
  [, id, text] = match;
}
return { id, text };
```

`match` could be null, or lengths between 1-3.

`id` and `text` need to be empty strings by default and only set if `match` is not null and of certain length.

**How can I shorten this up?**

Possibly avoiding the if statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that array destructing has the capability of providing default values.

```
const [, id = '', text = ''] = match;
return { id, text };
```

[Array Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring#Default_values)

Comment: Only for `undefined`, not for `null`